# set up c# Selenium webdriver to Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, vstest

I'm trying to set up my `Selenium webdriver for .Net` tests to `Jenkins`, first time to `Jenkins` never tried it before, but having some issues giveing a headache.

I installed `VSTest Runner plugin` in `Jenkins`, in `Configuration` I added `Path` to `VSTest` `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe` in VSTest installer.

[image: VSTestInstall]

And added run tests:

[image: runTests]

But getting following errors:

```
Error: The test source file "C:\Program" provided was not found.
Error: The test source file "Files" provided was not found.
Error: The test source file "(x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins" provided was not found.
Error: The test source file "Test" provided was not found.
Error: The test source file "App\workspace\RegressionTestLibrary\bin\Debug\RegressionTest.dll" provided was not found.
```

Looks like it read whitespace as a new-line, I'm not even sure doing right, anyone can enlight me? :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a *Windows Batch Command* instead of plugin. I will assume that you are using a single instance of Jenkins, not a Master-Slave structure (Jenkins with multiple nodes):

1. Go to **Jenkins Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties >** check ***Environment Variable*s** box and add ***Path*** Variable with the location of your VSTest runner. (Please see the attached picture for example)
   [First Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5dYI.png)
2. Go to your **Jenkins Jobs > Add *Build Step* > Execute Windows Batch command**
   and enter: `vstest.console.exe "{{ your_test.dll_location }}"`. The path is relative to the workspace Jenkins folder.
   [Second Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtHsy.png)

If you are using a node: 
Go to **Jenkins Dashboard > Your Node > Configure > Node Properties** check ***Environment Variable*** box and add ***Path*** variable with the location of your VSTest runner. Repeat the step 2 but don't forget to check the ***Restrict where this project can be run*** box in job configuration and select the ***label*** for your node.

The result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ha8M.png)

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, I fixed it by replacing 
`C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Jenkins Test App\workspace` with `{WORKSPACE}` So for you it should look like `{WORKSPACE}\RegressionTestLibrary\bin\Debug\RegressionTest.dll`, however I now have the issue that my build will pass, but now the console tells me

> Starting test discovery, please wait...
>
> Finished: SUCCESS

so my tests are never actually ran, this could be a separate issue, and for all I know you may not encounter it.